# Counting pollcount with COM2 THRE using x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have to write this assembly function that is called by pollcount_putc(char)

It takes a char, counts how many tests of COM2 THRE are done in the polling loop and then outputs it to COM2. Right now I am doing something incorrect as I am receiving all 0s.

Here is the code below:

```
 #Function call is pollcount_putc(c[i])
#COM2 base address is 0x2f8
.text
.globl _pollcount_putc
COMTWO = 0x2f8

_pollcount_putc:

    movl 4(%esp), %ecx #get character
    movl $COMTWO, %edx #set port address
    addl $5, %edx #get to LSR
    movl $0, %ebx #set counter to 0

loop:
    inb (%dx), %al #read in LSR byte
    andb $0x01, %al #isolate DR bit
    jz loop #if zero or not ready loop until
    movw $COMTWO, %dx #Reset dx with correct com address

comaddress:
    movb %cl, %al #move char input to output
    outb %al, (%dx) #output the char taken in
    addl $5, %edx #move back to LSR byte
countloop:
    incl %ebx #increment count
    inb (%dx), %al #read from LSR byte to get thre
    andb $0x20, %al #mask to look at thre
    jz countloop #if tx hr empty
end:
    movl %ebx, %eax #set counter to eax return register
    ret
    .end
```

If anyone has any ideas as to where my logic issues are that would be great.  I am not sure I am doing this right at all.

Update: I got this working  and above is the new code.  In a couple days i will post the answer below as well to close it out.

Comment: 90% of the secret of writing decent assembly code is to put a good comment on *every* statement.  And not "put back out" but a logical description of what it does.  You quit commenting at the exact point where you got hopelessly lost.  If you can't write a comment then inevitably you cannot write correct code.  Or get help since nobody can see what you were thinking.

Comment: I am going to post the updated code that works....with comments.  While you weren't wrong your comment wasn't helpful either.

Answer (score -1):

Does your c[i] have 4 bytes? If not, you should not use 4(%esp) to get its memory location.

Comment: That part is correct actually.  The stack pointer consumes 4 bytes of information and then the char passed it would be next so that is why i would add 4 to the stack pointer and then grab the content of that.